# Draft Js performance issue while editing large content

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

We are using Draft.js library and React Js to create online text editor. There is a noticeable lag between typed text and reflecting it on the screen and this behavior is mostly for the large editor content (JSON file size > 1MB). Is there a way to make it faster? Any advice on this is much appreciated!